# Why does initialization of my object with variadic template arguments require the definition of move constructor?

Tags: templates, c++11, g++, clang, variadic-templates

I want to create a local object of some `typename` `Type` in a template function:

```
template <typename Type, typename... Args>
void create_local(Args... args)
{
    Type val(args...);
}
```

Now, when I call this function with no arguments (where `Type` is a class with a non-copyable member):

```
struct T {
    std::mutex m;
};

int main()
{
    T t;               // OK: No use of move constructor
    create_local<T>(); // Error: Requires deleted move constructor!!!
}
```

[(coliru link)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed2eb680fe5e3212)

g++ (from 4.7.3 to 5.2) fails to compile and requires the definition of the move constructor of T? clang 3.7 compiles successfully.

Additionally, if I (1) remove `std::mutex` member from T, (2) declare default constructor for T, and (3) declare a deleted copy-constructor for T:

```
struct T {
    T() = default;
    T(const T&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    T t;               // OK: No use of move constructor
    create_local<T>(); // OK: No use of move constructor
}
```

all versions of g++ and clang compiles successfully. Why does g++ not compile for any type `Type` with non-copyable members?

Comment: Hmm, seems like a bug. Interestingly g++ will compile the above if you use braces rather than parentheses for the initialization.

Comment: Having read your comment, I looked for GCC Bugzilla and found these bug reports: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58089, https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59141

Answer (score 1):

According to Andrey Zholos's comment in [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58089) bug report:

> I also stumbled onto this bug, and bug 59141 is a duplicate.
>
> It appears the empty parameter pack is expanded as t({}) rather than t().
>
> There is a similar example in 14.5.3p6 that indicates obj should be value-initialized (not copy-constructed), and clang accepts this code.